# How can I do a LEFT OUTER JOIN select

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I do a select that: select all the proposta_id that exists in my table called San_Proposta and all proposta_id that exists in my table San_Negocio WHEN this proposta_id in San_Negocio has the column ValidaCaptacao = 0 AND ValidaVenda = 1 or the column ValidaVenda = 0 AND ValidaCaptacao = 1 AND the column Proposta_Id in San_Negocio can't be NULL ??

I don't know if I have to use the LEFT OUTER JOIN, but follow my attempt, that doesn't works correctly, because I have some data in San_Proposta.Proposta_Id that don't exists in San_Negocio.Proposta_Id but this data doesn't appears.

```
    SELECT San_Proposta.Proposta_Id 
    FROM San_Proposta
    LEFT OUTER JOIN San_Negocio
    ON San_Proposta.Proposta_Id = San_Negocio.Proposta_Id
    WHERE San_Negocio.Proposta_Id IS NOT NULL
    AND (San_Negocio.ValidaCaptacao = 1 AND San_Negocio.ValidaVenda = 0) 
    OR (San_Negocio.ValidaCaptacao = 0 AND San_Negocio.ValidaVenda = 1)
```

Comment: just to clarify - Proposta_Id can exist in either table or both correct? I don't see anything in the question that says that the Proposta_Id must atleast exist in the San_Proposta table if it exists at all. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: ALL San_Negocio.Proposta_Id exist in San_Proposta, but just some San_Proposta.Proposta_Id exist in San_Negocio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you test columns from a LEFT JOINed table in the WHERE clause, you force that join to behave as if it were an INNER JOIN. Instead, make those tests part of the join conditions. You'll also want to drop the `WHERE San_Negocio.Proposta_Id IS NOT NULL` as that results in an INNER JOIN as well.

```
SELECT San_Proposta.Proposta_Id 
    FROM San_Proposta
        LEFT OUTER JOIN San_Negocio
            ON San_Proposta.Proposta_Id = San_Negocio.Proposta_Id
                AND (San_Negocio.ValidaCaptacao = 1 AND San_Negocio.ValidaVenda = 0) 
                 OR (San_Negocio.ValidaCaptacao = 0 AND San_Negocio.ValidaVenda = 1)
```

Comment: But I got a problem now. The San_Negocio.ValidaCaptacao can't has the same value of San_Negocio.ValidaVenda. With this query, returns me some data that has this columns (ValidaCaptacao and ValidaVenda) with the same value. How can I return just the data that ValidaVenda is different then ValidaCaptacao ?

Comment: @Lucas_Santos: what is this same value you are seeing?

Comment: For example, I have 2 columns called ValidaCaptacao and ValidaVenda on my table San_Negocio. ValidaCaptacao and ValidaVenda can has just 2 values: 1 or 0. I don't want the data where both columns has the same value (ValidaVenda = 1 and ValidaCaptacao = 1, OR ValidaVenda = 0 and ValidaCaptacao = 0). I tryied put ValidaCapacao <> ValidaVenda, but returns the data where both columns has the same value included.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT San_Proposta.Proposta_Id 
FROM San_Proposta
INNER JOIN San_Negocio
ON San_Proposta.Proposta_Id = San_Negocio.Proposta_Id
WHERE (San_Negocio.ValidaCaptacao = 1 AND San_Negocio.ValidaVenda = 0) 
OR (San_Negocio.ValidaCaptacao = 0 AND San_Negocio.ValidaVenda = 1)
```